# Old sci-fi movie that has multiple alien spaceships with long necks and people being turned into piles of worms

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

My mom has asked me to help her find an old sci-fi movie that has multiple alien spaceships with long necks and people being turned into piles of worms.

She believes that the movie is from the 70's or maybe the early 80's. I have not been able to find anything that even remotely resembles what she is talking about. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the aliens or the spaceships have long necks? assuming former, the long necks reminds me of non-aliens that were developed in a lab seeking iirc a cancer cure and it was a british movie. do not recall name but not probably the movie u seek anyway.

Comment: Such aliens with long neck could be found in [Laserblast](https://youtu.be/XPfas-JvbeY?t=12), but seems there are no any "piles of worms".

Comment: @Jeff Stuck - Please clarify whether the "long necks" part applies to the alien/s or the spaceship, as that ambiguity is causing some confusion. It would also help to clarify whether there was one alien, or more than one.

Comment: The cancer cure monster movie that Releseabe refers to is "Island of Terror", from 1966. Regarding the question, the long-necked spaceships remind me of George Pal's Martian fighting machines from 1953's "War of the Worlds".

Answer (score 6):

I think this might be [Night of the Creeps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Creeps).

It's from 1986, so the era fits.

The movie has alien parasites that infect people then the people split open and they release more alien parasites.

The ships look like this:
[image]

That's a shot of the "head" of the ship and part of the neck (it's the only shot I could find).

Answer (score 2):

Could it be "The Thing"?

[image]

The spaceship is only visible from the outside, but "aliens" with long "necks" can be seen. Also people are turned into "piles of worms" by the alien bacteria.

The timeframe also fits: 1982.

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084787/

Answer (score 1):

A spaceship with a long neck is a good match for a Klingon Bird of Prey.

Star Trek III the Search for Spock meets your time frame and slo features some worm like creatures. See these clip from youtube...

Your question is very vague though so there is still some room for doubt.

Comment: yeah, u found a spaceship, not the aliens, with a long "neck".

Comment: note that the question actually says "alien spaceship with long necks" its not clear at all if they mean aliens or alien spaceship. If the op clarifies that it would be great.

Comment: actually, nowhere does it actually say that the aliens have long necks. what is confusing is that spacecraft are not usually considered to have necks, but seems that is maybe what OP meant -- having said that, the image of the Klingon vessel certainly shows a long-necked spaceship. The worms might be confusing the Klingon delicacy (or is it their junk food? or equiv of Brussel sprouts or some other healthy but unpalatable to Klingon kids?) is indeed worms (blood worms -- does vegas have a Klingon-themed restaurant? money making opportunity...)

Comment: @releseabe I mean... wondering why st: bird of prey, and not [war of the worlds invaders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_War_of_the_Worlds_(1953_film)) if they are going spaceships with long necks!

Comment: @releseabe Now that we've got more detail I can see that my answer is way off the mark, and I think you could be right about war of the worlds. The spaceships from the George Pal version would be a good match. Can;t recall any worms in that one though...

Comment: @skyjack i did not mention war of the worlds that i recall. lexible did. i wonder if Jeff Stuck's mom confused the Martian blood vines with worms that humans had been turned into which in an indirect way, since they consume humans, is very vaguely correct except the vines are not worms.

Comment: Ok so my mom said the spaceships from war or the world's looks very similar to the one she is thinking about she said the lasers they shoot turned into piles of white worms or white goo something like that and she thinks Roddy McDowell was in it

Comment: @JeffStuck take a look at a film called laser blast from 1978. Never seen it myself but found it on IMDB by searching for sf films with Roddy Mcdowall. here's a link https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077834/?ref_=ttls_li_tt